# how to know if system is completely idle

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, power-management

I am trying to figure out, how can we know if the system is idle? I want to suspend the system if it is idle for some x minutes. I tried to find for this and tried the below script code as well

```
#!/bin/bash

idletime=$((1000*60)) # 1 minute in milliseconds

while true; do
    idle=`xprintidle`
    echo $idle
    if (( $idle > $idletime )); then
       echo -n "mem" >> /sys/power/state
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

But xprintidle only monitors the mouse and keyboard activity to increment it's counter.
Now if I run a program in infinite loop then also it will suspend the system.

The other option was extracting the idle time from /proc/stat over an interval of time, but on different systems I see different range of values for cpu idle, if I leave the system without any activity.

Can some one help me how can I implement suspension of system.

Comment: Well you could monitor what the cpu usage range is when the system is idle, allowing leeway for cron jobs etc, and then test if the cpu usage stays within this range, as well as testing for input. This seems to be overcomplicating the problem a bit imo

Comment: @limecore for sandeep's problem I don't think that monitoring CPU is a good idea. When someone typing a text, CPU changing very few *(Tbh depends on a text editor too)*. Within amount of an application that decided to index something, or send report, etc, that is still considered to be «idle». Btw, the topicstarter in the post said almost this when mentioned that(s)he already tried to monitor `/proc/stat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff can, and will, happen at any time. Something gets kicked off by cron. Someone's sleep() call finishes, and it wakes up for a few milliseconds.

I'd say, come up with some meaningful heuristic. For example, periodically sample /proc/loadavg, and if the load average stays below some threshold, for a given period of time, assume that the system is now idle.

Comment: I will surely look on to that, but will the loadaverage vary from system to sytem? I need to check on this and also need to check what can be the threshold limit for that. Thanks for your response Sam.

Comment: /proc/loadavg always changes, even on the same system. There is no official definition of what "idle" means. You'll have to use your own definition.

Comment: yup my observation is pretty same and what I see is it vary drastically from system to system and also the applications which were already open. I just wanted to check, that the idle tread runs on the processor when there is nothing to do. Is there any means we can know when the idle thread is being scheduled.

Comment: There is no "idle thread" in Linux. You're thinking of some other, technically inferior operating system. When there are no processes to be scheduled, the kernel stops the CPU until the next interrupt, and the time is charged as "idle".